# Get total count of days between two dates Linq C#

Tags: entity-framework

I want to get total number of days between two dates using Linq C# with Entity Framework 6. My issue is I need a where clause condition and  finding it difficult to subtract the dates. I am getting errors when I run my code below. Any help to achieve this will be appreciated.

```
var finalexams = report.Select(x =>                 
                 new ReportVieModel
                {

                   EnglishDates = x.admin.mastertablebles.Where(d => d.EndDate == null).Select(s => DbFunctions.DiffDays(s.beginDate, DateTime.Today)),


                }).Distinct();
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Try moving `DateTime.Today` into a variable before the query. That property isn't going to translate to SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What type of data does EnglishDate represent?

The only condition I see is that the final date can be null, I suppose this will return more than one value and you will need a list.

I don't understand if you want a list with the start date and the number of days because you could do this according to the model:

**Model:**

```
public class ReportViewModel
{
    public DateTime? Date { get; set;  }

    public int? NumberDays { get; set; }
}
```

**LINQ:**

```
List<ReportViewModel> list = (from p in x.admin.mastertablebles
                              where p.EndDate == null
                              select new ReportViewModel() { Date = p.beginDate,  NumberDays = DbFunctions.DiffDays(p.beginDate, DateTime.Now) })
                             .Distinct().ToList();
```

Or you want a list that only contains the number of days:

**LINQ:**

```
var numberDays = (from p in x.admin.mastertablebles
                  where p.EndDate == null
                  select DbFunctions.DiffDays(p.beginDate, DateTime.Now))
                 .Distinct().ToList();
```